# programmatically add dynamic AJAX controls to an ASP page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

Is it possible to programmatically add dynamic AJAX controls to an ASP page?

Now I create Textbox, Listbox dynamically in Page_Init Event. I have a Hover Menu that only attaches to the first ListBox.

I need to add it to the loop that creates the other controls so that it will be available on each List box.

Here is some of my code...

```
Dim num As Integer = Session("lineNums")     ' Determines how many text boxes need to be created based on carriage returns from textblock. 

Dim MainContent As ContentPlaceHolder = CType(Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder) 

Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(MainContent.FindControl("PlaceHolder1"), PlaceHolder) 

For I = 1 To num 

   Dim txtD As New TextBox 
   txtD.ID = "txtDEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(txtD) 

   Dim litCtrlD As New Literal 
   litCtrlD.ID = "litCtrlD" & I.ToString("D2") 
   litCtrlD.Text = "<br />" 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlD) 

   txtD.Text = "ENGLISH" 

   Dim txtA As New TextBox 
   txtA.ID = "txtAEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(txtA) 

   Dim litCtrla As New Literal 
   litCtrla.ID = "litCtrla" & I.ToString("D2") 
   litCtrla.Text = "<br />" 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrla) 

   Dim txtE As New TextBox 
   txtE.ID = "txtEEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(txtE) 

   Dim litCtrlE As New Literal 
   litCtrlE.ID = "litCtrlE" & I.ToString("D2") 
   litCtrlE.Text = "<br />" 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlE) 

   txtE.Text = "TRANSLATION" 

   Dim txtB As New TextBox 
   txtB.ID = "txtBEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(txtB) 

   AddHandler txtB.TextChanged, AddressOf txtBChanged 

   Dim litCtrl As New Literal 
   litCtrl.ID = "litCtrl" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrl) 

   Dim lstF As New ListBox 
   lstF.ID = "lstFEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(lstF) 

   Dim litCtrlF As New Literal 
   litCtrlF.ID = "litCtrlF" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlF) 

   Dim lstG As New ListBox 
   lstG.ID = "lstGEdit" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(lstG) 

   AddHandler lstG.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstGChanged 

   Dim litCtrlG As New Literal 
   litCtrlG.ID = "litCtrlG" & I.ToString("D2") 
   ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlG) 

Next I
```

I need to add the Hover Menu somewhere in this code area.

```
Dim lstG As New ListBox
lstG.ID = "lstGEdit" & I.ToString("D2")
ph.Controls.Add(lstG)

AddHandler lstG.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf lstGChanged

Dim litCtrlG As New Literal
litCtrlG.ID = "litCtrlG" & I.ToString("D2")
ph.Controls.Add(litCtrlG)
```

Thanks forany help on this one.

**EDIT**: I have added the following code to the Page_Init Event to try and build the Hover menus but am getting an error as described below....

```
' ************************************
' Creating Hover
  Dim hoverMenuExt As New AjaxControlToolkit.HoverMenuExtender
  hoverMenuExt.ID = "hovExtEdit" & I.ToString("D2")     **
  ph.Controls.Add(hoverMenuExt)

  Dim litHoverMenuExt As New Literal
  litHoverMenuExt.ID = "litHoverMenuExt" & I.ToString("D2")
  ph.Controls.Add(litHoverMenuExt)
```

** Line with error: Variable "hoverMenuExt.ID" is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Any ideas on this part?

Comment: `Dim hoverMenuExt As New AjaxControlToolkit.HoverMenuExtender`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI, this is a great link that shows how to dynamically add standard controls.

[Click here.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page)

This provides an in-depth review of the dynamic control too elaborate to detail here.